# Issue in Throttle time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I added the following method in `trait ThrottlesLogins` in Laravel 5.5

```
protected function TotalRegisterAttemptsLeft($request) {
    $this->incrementAttempts($request);
    return $this->limiter()->retriesLeft($this->resolveRequestSignature($request), 3);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('apiregister', 
    array(
        'uses'          =>  'API\Register\RegisterAPIController@Registration', 
        'as'            =>  'apiRegister',
        'middleware'    =>  'throttle:3,1'
    )
);
```

This method was working perfectly in 5.4, Let me explain the problem.

I have a register POST route which has max 3 attempts. After using all the three attempts user will have to wait for 60 seconds.

But the problem is, lets say I spends 12 seconds during the three attempts. After 3 attempts, it say, Please try after 48 seconds. It should instead say, Please try again after 60 seconds.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: what are you expecting to call that method?

Comment: This method is just informing the user that they are left with this much attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is either a bug or intended behavior in the ThrottleRequests-Middleware. You can easily reproduce this when changing the existing integration test:

```
public function test_lock_opens_immediately_after_decay()
{
    Carbon::setTestNow(null);

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'yes';
    })->middleware(ThrottleRequests::class.':2,1');

    $response = $this->withoutExceptionHandling()->get('/');
    $this->assertEquals('yes', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertEquals(2, $response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Limit'));
    $this->assertEquals(1, $response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Remaining'));

    Carbon::setTestNow(
        Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10)
    );

    $response = $this->withoutExceptionHandling()->get('/');
    $this->assertEquals('yes', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertEquals(2, $response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Limit'));
    $this->assertEquals(0, $response->headers->get('X-RateLimit-Remaining'));

    Carbon::setTestNow(
        Carbon::now()->addSeconds(58)
    );

    try {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling()->get('/');
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $this->assertEquals(429, $e->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertEquals(2, $e->getHeaders()['X-RateLimit-Limit']);
        $this->assertEquals(0, $e->getHeaders()['X-RateLimit-Remaining']);
        $this->assertEquals(2, $e->getHeaders()['Retry-After']);
        $this->assertEquals(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(2)->getTimestamp(), $e->getHeaders()['X-RateLimit-Reset']);
    }
}
```

I just added

```
Carbon::setTestNow(
    Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10)
);
```

between the first and second request. This will then result in the following output from phpunit:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Integration/Http/ThrottleRequestsTest.php
PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.2.1
Configuration: /Volumes/Workspace/Projects/laravel/phpunit.xml.dist

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 172 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Illuminate\Tests\Integration\Http\ThrottleRequestsTest::test_lock_opens_immediately_after_decay
Failed asserting that -8 matches expected 2.

/Volumes/Workspace/Projects/laravel/tests/Integration/Http/ThrottleRequestsTest.php:54
```

I have created a PR with the failing test ~and once it's confirmed this is not intended behavior someone can start fixing it:~

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22725/files

edit: As stated in the PR, this is intended behavior. The middleware is designed for API rate limiting where you want to ensure that within a certain time frame x amount of requests are let through. For limiting password attempts you have to switch out the underlying RateLimiter.

As to why this worked before, I can not tell you.

Comment: how does not it give me complete 1 min? lets say I spends 12 seconds during the three attempts. After 3 attempts, it say, Please try after 48 seconds. It should instead say, Please try again after 60 seconds.

Comment: I understand, but with throttling through a rate limiter you want to allow a user let's say 100 req/min. For that you take the first request and start counting within the timer. If the limit is reached you don't block all requests for a full minute, but instead block any requests within this time frame. Then after 60secs since the first request it will start a new time frame. This is what the component is intended for. You want something else, which means you need another middleware or use this middleware with your own custom limiter, instead of the default RateLimiter.

Comment: there is one more strange behavior in 5.5. In 5.4, I was able to get different retries for register page and different retries for login page. But now, this functionality is made common for any api url.

Comment: That sounds like it was intentional. Usually you want to rate limit the whole API and not certain endpoints independently. I just checked the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0), but found nothing on theThrottle-middleware, but there have been changes to the [middleware](https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/5.4...5.5#diff-1a53c7aaf17850b5989c419950f0bf5b) and the [RateLimiter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/5.4...5.5#diff-b137e2ee30cf6cc9f94a35f61d2bb8a9).

Comment: I also found that there is a trait [ThrottlesLogins](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php) you cold possibly use or build upon for your scenario.

Comment: if u can please answer here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389137/404-error-for-socket-io-on-localhost-xampp-laravel-5-5/48399283#48399283 Thanks a lot.