# 404 error for socket.io on localhost - XAMPP - Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using XAMPP, Window 8.1 , Laravel 5.5 on localhost

I wrote code for broadcasting in laravel using pusher and works fine. As pusher is very costly so, I am planning to move to socket.io

Added below link in master blade.

```
<script src="{{ asset('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
```

Also ran this command in cmd

```
npm install express ioredis socket.io --save
```

but this shows me an error below.

[image]

If you see the screenshot, the 404 error is for url is

> http://localhost:1234/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4VVdoo

but my url is

> http://localhost:1234/my/learning/public/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4VVdoo

Any idea, why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to install below packages.

```
npm install -g laravel-echo-server
```

**[then following the step by step instruction as give here](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)**

Finally put below code before any js file.

```
<script src="http://{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:1234/my/learning/public/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4VVdoo` it looks as though your project  directiry is not resolving correctly. This can be because of an incorrect `.htaccess`, mod_rewrite not being enabled, or in the case of nginx, an incorrect try files directive within a server block. I'd double those appropriate configuration and see if the problem persists there after

Comment: I added js script part also. That has correct path. You can see the js script reference in my question. I have no problem with js. Why just with socket.js?

Comment: `asset('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js')` according to this you should have `socket.io.js` in `public/'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js`. It looks like you're trying to linking directly to the `node_modules` directory instead. Are you using a build tool like webpack or gulp to copy resources to the public directory?